# Display more than 1 year in Kendo UI for jQuery?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-gantt

Some clinical studies can take up to 5 years or more, and I want to be able to show an entire study and its sub-tasks in a Kendo Gantt chart.  I want to show periods of time longer than the current maximum of 1 year that is built into Kendo UI for jQuery v2018.3.1017,  is that possible?

I'd like to be able to show a maximum of 6 years. Ideally the header would change to be able to see Quarter/Year rather than Month.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The built-in views for the Gantt are: "day", "week", "month" and "year". So if you need to show longer period you need to create a custom view. [Check the custom view example in the documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/scheduling/gantt/how-to/creating-custom-view). It shows how to create a multi-year view and display quarters as well.

Comment: We are indeed able to create custom views for quarter and different timelines when the time span is 1 year or less. However we are still not able to create views for periods of time longer than 1 year.  In clinical trials, we need to be able to show time spans of “3year” or “6year”.  The example you provided only has intervals of quarter year. Do you have example templates for more than year period. For long timespans having a simple header showing the year such as 2022, 2023, 2024, would be fine.

Comment: The name of the view in the documentation is not entirely correct - make sure to scroll to the right and note the headers. Here is an [example](https://dojo.telerik.com/UbehileT) starting from 2022 and ending by 2027.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close the loop: here is the response I received from the Telerik Support folks.

From the provided information I am not sure if the widget you intend to use is a Kendo Gantt or Scheduler. However, in both cases implementing a custom view will be needed. Below you will find links with examples of implementing custom views in Gantt and Scheduler:

[creating-custom-view](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/scheduling/gantt/how-to/creating-custom-view)

[timeline-with-dynamic-length](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/scheduling/scheduler/how-to/custom-views/timeline-with-dynamic-length)

[custom-view](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/scheduling/scheduler/how-to/custom-views/custom-view)